# Two wires on a single terminal on a switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I need to replace a switch. When I first took off the panel, I noticed two terminals plus a neutral so I assumed a single pole switch.

However, when I went to replace the switch, I found two wires going into one of the terminals, see picture. The top switch is the one that was already installed, the bottom switch is the partially wired new switch. I noticed the original switch (top one) has those little corrugated flaps on each terminal, presumably to hold two straight wires down. The bottom switch does not have these.

So, is there a name for the type of switch on the top? Or those little flaps? So I can buy that exact type. Or would it be okay to wire that pair that was screwed onto the same terminal on the old switch into a wire nut, then add a third wire into the nut that goes to my new switch on the bottom, so there is only one wire on the terminal?

So instead of

```
W1-\
    Terminal
W2-/
```

I'd have

```
W1-\
    Nut--W3--Terminal
W2-/
```

Some notes. Original switch is not three way, I don't think. At least not by design. There is no terminal on the opposite side, just the two you see plus a neutral.

Also I'm not sure what the two wires are for. For that switch, a light / fan combo comes on. From the room it looks like one device, but maybe it needs two hot wires? Don't know.

[image: wiring]

Comment: Not quite sure if they have a special name or just much better quality, 50 cents instead of 2 dollars.  When ever two wires are connected together by screws/wire nuts one wire is in, the other is out to something else.  Using a wire nut to connect two wires plus a short one to a screw is perfect and prefer for single screw connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What you want is a *specification grade* switch that supports back-wiring

The "screw and clamp" style of back-wiring that you see on the switch on the left in your photograph is characteristic of what are known as *specification grade* switches (vs. the "builder grade" switches used in lowest-cost construction, that use a "push in" backwire system instead).  So, I'd start by looking at spec grade switches from reputable electrical manufacturers (Eaton, Leviton, and Legrand).

You'll also want to trim down the bare ends of the hot wires entering that switch so they don't short to something else when the new switched is stuffed into the box.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen them referred to back or side clamped switches. They cost a little more but are great for what you've got. Your application just needs a hot wire for the fan and light but the second wire is a tapped hot going somewhere else, like an outlet. You can do exactly what you mentioned, take those two wires along with a short piece of wire and wire nut them together and use the short piece to energize the new switch. Cheaper switches have holes in the back where you can just insert the wires, commonly called backstabs. you don't want to use them.